# Prevent reading and writing to directory or mount point when block storage is not mounted

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have an application that depends on the data from a mount point, e.g. `/mnt/db`

What I need to prevent is any read/write to the directory when the actual block storage is not mounted, that is, *without modifying the application to do the check before doing the file system write in which I have no control of*. Usually happens during machine restarts and similar reboots.

In what way this can be achieved without scripting?

Comment: The main reason for this is that the application uses an embedded database and if the actual block storage is mounted it creates a new database and writes to the file system directly which is crucial not to happen.

Comment: `if grep -qw "/mnt/db" /proc/mounts; then echo "device mounted"; else echo "device not mounted"; fi` (added the `-w` word-regex option to prevent matching `"/mnt/db2"`, etc..)